# Is there a way to view data in 2 replicas in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cql, cqlsh

I am a newbie to Cassandra.I have created a keyspace in Cassandra in NetworkTopology Strategy with 2 replicas in one datacenter. Is there a cql command or some other way to view my data in two replicas?

Like `SELECT * FROM tablename in replica1 / replica2`

Whether there is another way such that I can visually see the data in two replicas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

So your question is not real clear "See the data in 2 replicas". If you ever want to validate your data, you can run some commands to visually see things.

The first thing you'd want to do is log onto the node you want to investigate. Go to the data directory of the interested table -> DataDir/keyspace/table. In there you'll see one or more files that look like *Data.db. Those are your sstables. Data in memory is flushed to sstables in certain scenarios. You want to be sure your data is flushed from memory to disk if you're validating (as you may not find what you're looking for otherwise). To do that, you issue a "nodetool flush" command (you can use the keyspace and table as parameters if you only want to flush the specific table).

Like I said, after that, everything in memory would be flushed to disk. So you'd be able to see your sstables (again, *Data.db) files. Once you have those sstables, you can run the "sstabledump" command on each sstable to see the data that resides in them, thus validating your data.

If you have only a few rows you want to validate and a lot of nodes, you can find which node the rows would reside by running "nodetool getendpoints" with the keyspace, table, and partition key. That will tell you every node that will have the data. That way you're not guessing which node the row(s) should be on. Unfortunately, there is no way to know which sstable the rows should exist in (and it could be more than one if updates/deletes, etc. occurred). You'll have to go through each sstable on the specific node(s).

Hope that helps answer your question?

Good luck.

-Jim

Comment: I was thinking the same thing...that dumping out the SSTable is really the only way to see that.

Comment: Hi Jim.. Thank you so much for the reply. Actually I am testing the Cassandra whether we can move on to it. So I installed it in my laptop and want to explore things. By saying that we create some replicas and it is stored on many nodes triggered me to look into it. By saying 'see the data in 2 replicas', I meant the same. After I did an insert I wanna see it on the replicas.If I manually down one node and wanted to see the differences between the replicas and try the nodetool repair option. Now I came over 'ccm' which is used to test the cluster in a laptop.

Answer (score 3):

You can for a specific partition. If you are sure `host1` is a replica (`nodetool getendpoints` or from query trace), then if you make your query with CL.ONE and explicitly to that host, the coordinator will always pick local first. So

```
Statement q = new SimpleStatement("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE key = X");
q.setHost("host1")
```

Where `host1` owns `X`.

For `SELECT * FROM tablename` its a bit harder because you are looking over entire data set and coordinator will send out multiple queries for each part of ring. If you do some queries with CL.ONE it will still only go to one node for each part of that range so if you set `q.enableTracing()` you can see what node answered for each range. You have no control over which coordinator picks so may take few queries.

If you just want to see if theres differences you can use preview repair. `nodetool repair --preview --full`.

Comment: Thank you so much Chris. Actually I wanted to test the replication feature in Cassandra and wanted to visually see the differences in data in two replicas by making one node down. And then I wanted to test the nodetool repair feature.